# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I am trying to show count report in stacked vertical bar chart using angular chart (ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked), but I'm getting the following error:

[image: Error]

dynamically build the data so for example 
//app.ts i declare

`array chartDataNGX:any[];`

then in constructor call `getChatrtData()` then in getchartdata i go something like

```
this.chartDataNGX.push( 
  {"name": "TEST2","series": [
      {"name": "Target","value": 40632},
      {"name": "Actual","value": 36953}, 
      {"name": "Projected","value": 31476}
  ]}, 
  {"name": "TEST3","series": [
      {"name": "Target","value": 40632}, 
      {"name": "Actual","value": 36953}, 
      {"name": "Projected","value": 31476}
      ]
  });
```

it fails with 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' so what am i doing wrong?

Please help.

Comment: dynamically build the data so for example

//app.ts
i declare array chartDataNGX:any[];

then in constructor call getChatrtData()

then in getchartdata i go something like

this.chartDataNGX.push(
{"name": "TEST2","series": [{"name": "Target","value": 40632},{"name": "Actual","value": 36953}, {"name": "Projected","value": 31476}]},
{"name": "TEST3","series": [{"name": "Target","value": 40632},{"name": "Actual","value": 36953}, {"name": "Projected","value": 31476}]}
);

it fails with 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'

so what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ngIf to avoid making graph if result is empty

```
  <div *ngIf="chartDataNGX.length">
    <ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked
      [view]="view"
      [scheme]="colorScheme"
      [results]="chartDataNGX"
      [gradient]="gradient"
      [xAxis]="showXAxis"
      [yAxis]="showYAxis"
      [legend]="showLegend"
      [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
      [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
      [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
      [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
      (select)="onSelect($event)">
    </ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked>
   </div>
```

Also typically we initialize variables in constructor, and leave methods to be done in `ngOnInit` life cycle hook

Comment: Tried with your suggestion but issue not resolved .getting below error :ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///ReportsModule/ReportsComponent.ngfactory.js:117)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (vendor.bundle.js:146579)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:145759)
    at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:146124)
    at execComponentViewsAction (vendor.bundle.js:146056)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:145765)

Comment: Issue has been resolved by adding *ngIf="showcharts" ..Thanks